# Trying to user register using Node.js API

Tags: node.js, api

I am creating Node restful API for User registration below is my code.

```
apiRoutes.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.name || !req.body.password) {
    res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please pass Name and Password.'});
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({ 
      name:req.body.name,
      password:req.body.password, 
      mobile:req.body.mobile
  });

  // save the user
  newUser.save(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.json({success: false, msg: 'Username already exists.'});
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.'});}
    });
  }
});
```

This code was working in previously but now I am trying to hit this API on postman then its throwing `success: false, msg: 'Username already exists.'`
I don't know whats going wrong. Above same code was working perfect in my last project. 
Please help whats wrong with this code.

Thanks

Comment: On that line if(err) res.json... try changing it to res.json(err) and paste the output here.

Comment: @Brian After add res.json(err) its showing an error i.e `Error: Can't sent headers after they are sent`

Comment: you must have something else then, perhaps a middleware: apiRoutes.use(fn... res.send()). might be best if you show all middleware involved in that route specifically.

Comment: but some times before it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

the code is fine. no changes in the code.
can elaborate more on this...what actually is going on

Comment: I am hitting api using `postman` its showing and error `Error: Can't sent after they are sent`

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot of your Postman screen (with the headers section expanded) when you're trying to send the request..........???????    you can also try this..................................................................................     You can access the Developer Tools window by right clicking anywhere inside Postman and selecting "inspect element". You can also go to chrome://inspect/#apps and then click "inspect" just below requester.html under the Postman heading.

Comment: Right click is not working on my Postman and how to send screenshot in Comment?

Comment: on the post answer there is a button of image upload the image after that i think you will get the link copy and paste link.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Simply I Dropped  the database and re run my app then now its working fine.